# Understanding TypeScript Encapsulation

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is how I organize my TypeScript Files:

```
MBZ (Folder)
    Utilities.ts
    Controls (Folder)
        Designer.ts
        Form.Ts
```

Coming from C#, my approach has been to create namespaces based on the folder structure.  So everything in the MBZ folder would have the namespace "MBZ" and everything in the Controls folder would have the namespace "MBZ.Controls".  This allows everything in the Controls folder to implicitly refer to anything in any of its antecedent folders.

So, this is an example of the aforementioned files:

#### Utilties.ts

```
namespace MBZ
{
    export function ProcessSelection()
    {
        // A Common Utility available to anything in the MBZ.* namespace
    }
}
```

#### Designer.ts

```
namespace MBZ.Controls
{
    export module Designer
    {
        export function Initialize()
        {
            // Initialize Control
        }

        export function OnSubmit()
        {
            // Calls common utility
            ProcessSelection();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Form.ts

```
namespace MBZ.Controls
{
    export module Form
    {
        export function Initialize()
        {
            // Initialize Control
        }

        export function OnSubmit()
        {
            // Calls common utility
            ProcessSelection();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Question

Based on everything that I have read, people are saying that Modules are the way to go and that you should explicitly import each module that you need within a file.  This seems odd to me - with the method above you never really have to explicitly refer to anything unless you are referring to something that is in a different Namespace chain (just like in C#).

So my question is: what is so bad about the above approach?

Comment: I agree with you, as far as I see it, a small kitten dies every time one explicitly have to reference a specific location in the file system to use another piece of organized code.

Comment: I agree - it seems like my approach is much better than having to make an explicit import whenever i want to use something -

Comment: .. unless we are talking about pure third-party libraries, then I can buy how we reference the file system. But with your own code... yikes.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is: what is so bad about the above approach?

Because C# has the concept of `main`. That is not true in JavaScript / TypeScript. Code starts executing as it is parsed. So not using modules means your code can break in brittle ways.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html

Comment: But if you write proper code, there won't be any auto-executing code except in quite specific cases. Or do you mean the internal setup of the compiled TS?

Comment: `there won't be any auto-executing code except in quite specific cases` Not quite. E.g. class inheritance, module spliting etc.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant by the internal setup of the compiled TS. Should/could be solved by the compiler doing proper dependency analysis.

Comment: Hmmm - I'm not sure I get what you mean - it seems like as long as you reference the dependent files in order of dependency (i.e. files at the root first), then it won't be brittle?  If instead of doing my layout i referenced each required module, I would still have to load the files containing the dependent modules first anyways, right?

Comment: @William Thing is that those external modules are meant to go through a module loader that loads the necessary files when needed. So you don't have to care about the order, you *only* have to point out each and every file you use, everywhere. 